# Rudin, Riesz Representation theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

In the Reisz representation theorem, page 40 real and complex analysis, there's a preliminary that I don't understand.

After defining for each open $V$ the measure $\mu$ is defined as

$$
\mu(V) = \sup \left\{ \Lambda f : f \prec V \right\}
$$

from such definition we deduce both monotonicity and for each open $E$ we have

$$
\mu(E) = \inf \left\{ \mu(V) : E \subset V, \;V \; \text{open} \right\}.
$$

After this it states

> Let $M_F$ the class of all $E \subset X$ which satisfy two conditions
>   :
>   1. $\mu(E) < \infty$;
>   2. $\mu(E) = \sup \left\{ \mu(K) : K \subset E, K \; \text{compact} \right\}$

What I don't understand is how can be stated that $M_F$ is not empty.

Comment: $M_F$ must exist, since it's well-defined. Your question might be asking what can we say about "Is there any sets in $M_F$?". The question is answered later in the proof of Riesz's Representation Theorem in Rudin's book.

Comment: I don't understand the question: A priori, $M_F$ contains the empty set, and is therefore $M_F \neq \emptyset$. What else does one need to know?

Comment: @CaveJohnson Yes's sorry, basically I was asking if that $M_F$ is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $\emptyset\in M_F$, since the only $f$ such that $f\prec\emptyset$ is $f=0$ and so $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.  So $M_F$ is nonempty.